# How to optimize a CSV loader with pprof?

Tags: regex, csv, go, concurrency

I am trying to optimize a CSV loading process that is basically doing a regex search in a large CSV file (+4GB - 31033993 records for my experiment)
I managed to build a multiprocessing logic to read the CSV but when I analyze the CPU profiling using `pprof` I think my regex search is not optimized. Could you help me improve this code so that it can read the CSV much quickly?

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/pprof"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func processFile(path string) [][]string {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error:", err)
    }
    var pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^.*foo.*$`)
    numCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
    jobs := make(chan string, numCPU+1)

    fmt.Printf("Strategy: Parallel, %d Workers ...\n", numCPU)

    results := make(chan []string)
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for w := 1; w <= numCPU; w++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go parseRecord(jobs, results, wg, pattern)
    }
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            jobs <- scanner.Text()
        }
        close(jobs)
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    lines := [][]string{}
    for line := range results {
        lines = append(lines, line)
    }

    return lines
}

func parseRecord(jobs <-chan string, results chan<- []string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, pattern *regexp.Regexp) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for j := range jobs {
        if pattern.MatchString(j) {
            x := strings.Split(string(j), "\n")
            results <- x
        }

    }
}

func split(r rune) bool {
    return r == ','
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("perf.data")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()

    pathFlag := flag.String("file", "", `The CSV file to operate on.`)
    flag.Parse()
    lines := processFile(*pathFlag)
    fmt.Println("loaded", len(lines), "records")
}
```

When I process the file without any regex constraint I am getting a reasonable computing time (I simply load the parsed string into the 2D array without any `pattern.MatchString()`)

`Strategy: Parallel, 8 Workers ...
loaded 31033993 records
2018/10/09 11:46:38 readLines took 30.611246035s`

Instead, when I run the above code with the Regex constraint I am getting this result:

`Strategy: Parallel, 8 Workers ...
loaded 143090 records
2018/10/09 12:04:32 readLines took 1m24.029830907s`

Comment: Backtracking is a regex issue. I added a regex tag.

Answer (score 1):

MatchString looks for any match on the string
So you can get rid of the anchors and the wildcarding
The wildcarding at both ends is usually slow in regexp engines

example showing this on go 1.10

```
package reggie

import (
        "regexp"
        "testing"
)

var pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^.*foo.*$`)
var pattern2 = regexp.MustCompile(`foo`)

func BenchmarkRegexp(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                pattern.MatchString("youfathairyfoobar")
        }
}

func BenchmarkRegexp2(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                pattern2.MatchString("youfathairyfoobar")
        }
}
$ go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkRegexp-4        3000000           471 ns/op
BenchmarkRegexp2-4      20000000           101 ns/op
PASS
ok      _/Users/jsandrew/wip/src/reg    4.031s
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice tip I was not aware of.

Comment: This is much better `readLines took 31.606206481s` - Appart from this change, do you see anything else that can be improved in the program structure ? - The regrex pattern will be feeded dynamically

Comment: Do some more profiling and see what might be good to try next